# Android - how to use a Maps fragment in a Navigation architecture

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, androidx, android-navigation

I have hit a point in my app where I find myself sharing data between Activities in a clumsy way - so I have decided to try switching most of the app to a single Activity (in order to use a single ViewModel across screens), using the Navigation components to swap Fragments instead of changing Activities.

It seems that for each destination I need an xml layout file and a fragment class which looks like this:

```
class DestinationFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_destination_layout, container, false)

        return view
    }
}
```

(I'm actually using Java but could only find Kotlin examples.) [source](https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/NavigationBasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/navigationsample/InGame.kt)

However I'm not sure what to do with a Maps screen. I've currently got it as its own Activity:

**activity_maps.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MapsActivity">

<!--    Toolbar stuff     -->

<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/container_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/my_toolbar"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
</FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MapsActivity.java**

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    //Create the activity
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                 .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Check if user has location permissions granted
        if (!locationPermissionCheck()) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
        } else {
            setupMap(); //custom function defined elsewhere
        }
    }
```

So my question - if currently I have an Activity which fetches a Map Fragment, to fit into the Navigation architecture do I now need a Fragment which fetches a Map Fragment? i.e. something like...

```
public class MapDestinationFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_view, container, false);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
             .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Check if user has location permissions granted
    if (!locationPermissionCheck()) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},1);
    } else {
        setupMap(); //custom function defined elsewhere
    }

}
```

If this is the solution, is it ok to have a Fragment within a Fragment? Or would I be better off keeping it a separate Activity and just accepting the data sharing issue?

Thanks!